# CFLOCK : what scope to use?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have a function which generate a token for next event. let's call this eventID. This is numeric but stored as a varchar due to business reasons. This function can be called from multiple places within the application and to avoid race conditions to avoid generating same ID for different users a application scope lock was added. But still in few cases same ID was generated for 2 different events.

```
<cffunction name="getEventID" returntype="string">
  <cfset var newID = "">
  <cflock scope="Application" timeout="5" throwontimeout="true">
   <cfquery name="qry" datasource="#DSN#">
     SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(int, eventID) AS eventID
     FROM events WHERE ISNUMERIC(eventID) = 1
     ORDER BY CONVERT(int, eventID) DESC  
   </cfquery>
  <cfset newID = qry.eventID + 1>
 </cflock>
<cfreturn newID>
</cffunction>
```

Is there something wrong with the implementation of CFLOCK?

Comment: From your query it seems are trying to access the latest ID from the database, but I don't see how that can guarantee a unique value at each call.

Comment: Also imo, using `<cflock>` here wont fix anything for you.

Comment: @RRK, will you care to explain why it won't give unique value every time?

Comment: Well, if you are calling this after each time you are inserting a new event, this could work(still it wont be perfect just because multiple simultaneous inserts can happen from different places).

Comment: Is SELECT SELECT a typo? Also, I take it that eventID is not the primary key?

Comment: First, I would use named locks instead of a scope lock. Second, you need to update the DB inside this lock otherwise another thread could call this code prior to the update and could get the same id.

Comment: @JamesAMohler, yes that is typo. Will fix that

Comment: @Redtopia, You could be leading me to something. Do you mean if I am not updating the Db, just reading it, another thread can read  and get the same ID?

Comment: @CFML_Developer yes... exactly. After you make your next ID, update the DB. That would be thread safe. But there are better ways to do this... maybe you’re constrained by other factors. You could let the DB make the ID on insert.

Comment: I would let the DB do this work. Your function is only getting the most recently inserted ID and adding 1. It is completely possible for your code to select an ID and another to select the same ID, especially since you aren't doing anything yet with your `newID`.  And I'm not sure what business requirement you could have if you are checking if your `eventID` is numeric and then trying to `convert()` it to an `int`. This could easily throw an error or return an unexpected result. TSQL's `isNumeric()` is about as trustworthy as CF's is. It'll still see "`+`" as `numeric`.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=05c8ae4e6201e98cb21c55d9a83a357d  <<< The fun values that SQL `isNumeric()` sees as `true`.

Comment: @Shawn, I see the point you are trying to make, but we have only numbers in the field and sometimes numbers and child element so like 10819-09 or 10922-01 etc. We ignore the part after hyphen.

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using? You may run into issues with `convert()` for `10819-09`. That's not a valid number and won't convert.

Comment: I've seen some legacy code do this - query for highest value ID, increment it, and use that id for the next ID. To modernize, you could create a new, auto-incrementing ID field and use the existing ID field as a public "key" to the record. When creating a new keys, use something to generate a unique value, like `CreateUUID()`